# need help for proper way to write codes for create "loadmore" button and "like" button for posts

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I create a load more button for load more posts from the database but when I add like button for that if one time clicks on load more button and then click on the like button, `like.php` file runs two times and adds two lines in likes table. if I click 2 times on load more then like.php file runs 3 times and...
I want to know how I should create a loadmore button and like the button to works fine.

this is simple of my codes:

posts.php :

```
<div id="comnts2"></div>
<button id="btn2" >load more</button><script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var comco2 = 2;
  var offset2 = 0;
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "ld_comco.php",
        data: { comnco2 : comco2, offset2 : offset2}
      })
      .done(function(msg2) {

          $("#btn2").hide();
        } else {
       $("#comnts2").append(msg2);

      });

    offset2 = offset2 + comco2;
  });
  $("#btn2").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

ld_comco.php:

```
<?php
$comnco2=$_POST['comnco2'];
$offset2=$_POST['offset2'];

$rzp=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts` WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC limit $offset2, $comnco2");

  while($rp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rzp)){
    $sid=$rz['id'];
    $lik=$rz['lik'];
    echo $sid."<br>";

    /*like*/
    echo'<img class="li_ik1" data-id="'.$sid.'" src="pc3/up.png">'.$lik.' Likes</img>';
?>
    </span>
<?php }?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var uid=<?php echo $uid;?>;

  $(document).on("click", ".li_ik1", function() {
    var psid = $(this).data('id');
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "like.php",
          data: {psid: psid, uid: uid}
        }).done();
  }); 
});
</script>
```

like.php:

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['psid'];
$uid=$_POST['uid'];

$Y=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `t_plik` (pid,uid) VALUES ('$id','$uid')");
$Q=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `tbl_users_posts` SET lik=lik+1 WHERE id='$id'");
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you bind your like button multiple times globally. Each time you load the content from `ld_comco.php` you also call `$(document).on("click", ".li_ik1", ...)` in the  `$(document).ready` block, which means you bind all ".li_ik1" buttons on the entire document (but some of them has already been bind).

I would remove the `$(document).ready(...)` block from the `ld_comco.php` and move the logic into the `posts.php` right before you render your content. A further positive aspect is you have your business logic at one place.

KEEP IN MIND: You get a response of buttons in msg2, thats why you do not need to filter `$msg2` anymore. But if you wrap your buttons with further html tags in `ld_comco.php`, your buttons will be on a deeper level, so  you need to use a selector again, like you did with `.on("click", ".li_ik1", ...)`.

posts.php

```
...
var $msg2 = $(msg2);

// Now you bind only the loaded buttons instead of 
// the buttons in the entire document for multiple times
$msg2.on("click", function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var psid = $element.data('id');
  var uid = $element.data('uid');

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "like.php",
    data: {psid: psid, uid: uid}
  }).done();
});

$("#comnts2").append($msg2);
...
```

In your `ld_comco.php` you need to add the `data-uid="'.$uid.'"` and remove the `script` block. Then your file should look like this:

```
<?php
$comnco2=$_POST['comnco2'];
$offset2=$_POST['offset2'];

$rzp=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts` WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY id DESC limit $offset2, $comnco2");

while($rp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rzp)){
  $sid=$rz['id'];
  $lik=$rz['lik'];
  echo $sid."<br>";

  /*like*/
  echo'<img class="li_ik1" data-id="'.$sid.'" data-uid="'.$uid.'" src="pc3/up.png">'.$lik.' Likes</img>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#btn2").trigger("click");`
this in `posts.php` means click the `#btn2`
so after clicking it, you click it again

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var comco2 = 2;
  var offset2 = 0;
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "ld_comco.php",
        data: { comnco2 : comco2, offset2 : offset2}
      })
      .done(function(msg2) {
          $("#btn2").hide();
        } else {
       $("#comnts2").append(msg2);
      });
    offset2 = offset2 + comco2;
  });
```

```
$("#btn2").trigger("click");
```

```
});
</script>
```